# How do you merge the item values from 2 separate arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm not looking to push the values from one array into another, or concatenate them but simply sum the item values from each - either into a new array, or alternatively amending either arrayOne or arrayTwo with the values from the other   e.g.

```
var arrayOne = [1,2,3,4,5]
var arrayTwo = [2,4,6,8,10]
// loop / function..
var newArray = [3,6,9,12,15]
OR arrayOne = [3,6,9,12,15]
```

I thought this would be straightforward but this requires 2 loops running at the same time?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are both array always have the same length?

Comment: Assuming boths `arrays` are of equivalent `length`: `const newArray = arrayOne.map((x, i) => x + arrayTwo[i])`

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrayOne = [1,2,3,4,5];
var arrayTwo = [2,4,6,8,10];
var newArray = [];

newArray = arr1.map((item,index)=>{
    return item + arr2[index]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could collect all wanted array for adding values at the same index in an array and reduce the arrays.

This works with an arbitrary count of arrays.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    array2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
    result = [array1, array2].reduce(
        (a, b) => (b.forEach((v, i) => a[i] = (a[i] || 0) + v), a)
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Array's `map()`:

```js
var arrayOne = [1,2,3,4,5];
var arrayTwo = [2,4,6,8,10];
var newArray = arrayOne.map( (item, i) => item += arrayTwo[i] );

console.log(newArray);
```